# haystack search on multivaluefield

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I am trying to search on multivaluefield.

search index:

```
class UserIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    user_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='first_name',null=True)
    education_institute = indexes.MultiValueField(null=True)

    def prepare_education_institute(self, obj):
        return [education.institute for education in obj.educations.all()]
```

Search on username works ok but I don't get any results when I search on education_institute.

```
user_text.txt:

{{ object.first_name }}
{% for education in object.education_institute %}
{{ education }}
{% endfor %}
```

I have tried many things but nothings has worked.
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This could be improved slightly, it would help if you would give example of some of the things you have tried.

Comment: I have tried different prepare methods but nothing has worked